# javascript multiply 2 number show total and gtotal but show only one value?

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript calculation. multiply 2 numbers: `number 1 * number 2 = total` and how g-total but working only one value display?

**I have need number 1 * number 2 = total and show Gtotal so please help and share a valuable idea...**

**HTML**

```
<input
  name="per_hour"
  id="per_hour"
  class="form-control"
  value=""
  onblur="perhour()"
  placeholder="0"
/>

<input
  name="per_hour_x"
  id="per_hour_x"
  class="form-control"
  onblur="perhour()"
  value=""
  placeholder="0.00"
/>
```

**Total**

```
<input
  name="per_hour_total"
  id="per_hour_total"
  class="form-control"
  value=""
  placeholder="0.00"
/>
```

**G-Total**

```
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control total-fare"
  id="total"
  disabled
  value="<?= $booking->total_fare ?>"
/>

<script>
  function perhour() {
    var per_hour = document.getElementById("per_hour").value;
    var per_hour_x = document.getElementById("per_hour_x").value;
    var amts = document.getElementById("total").value;
    var totaperhour = Number(per_hour) * Number(per_hour_x);
    var totalamt = Number(totaperhour) + Number(amts);

    $("#per_hour_total").val(totaperhour).toFixed(2); //working
    $("#total").val(totalamt).toFixed(2); //not working
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ok thanks you succession for me.

Comment: you should put your HTML code too

Comment: You may use `console.log(totalamt)` to show the content of the variable of totalamt in console.

Comment: please add your html code

Comment: hi sir i am sharing html code so please share your valiable idea

Comment: sorry, but I can't find the 'per_hour_total' element，I want to compare ‘per_hour_total’ with ‘total’， so can you make up this？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `$('#per_hour_total').val(totaperhour.toFixed(2));` and not `$('#per_hour_total').val(totaperhour).toFixed(2);`

```js
function perhour() {
  var per_hour = document.getElementById("per_hour").value;
  var per_hour_x = document.getElementById("per_hour_x").value;
  var amts = document.getElementById("total").value;
  var totaperhour = Number(per_hour) * Number(per_hour_x);
  var totalamt = Number(totaperhour) + Number(amts);

  $('#per_hour_total').val(totaperhour.toFixed(2));
  $('#total').val(totalamt.toFixed(2)); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  total
  <input type="text" class="form-control total-fare" disabled id="total" value="">
</div>
<div>
  per_hour
  <input name="per_hour" id="per_hour" class="form-control" value="" onblur="perhour()" placeholder="0">
</div>
<div>
  per_hour_x
  <input name="per_hour_x" id="per_hour_x" class="form-control" onblur="perhour()" value="" placeholder="0.00">
</div>
<div>
  per_hour_total
  <input name="per_hour_total" id="per_hour_total" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="0.00">
</div>
```